# how to make a tic tac toe game using only context.save/context.restore, if statements, canvas and animations?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, canvas

[Letter O](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytt3i.png)
[Letter X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgPpp.png)

How to make a tic tac toe game using only context.save/context.restore, if statements, canvas, and animations? I'm also trying to make it so that if image X is displayed in box 1, image O can't be displayed in the same box so you can't cheat.

I do not know how to prevent someone to put image O on image X, vice versa. Please, someone, show me a way to prevent people to place an O on top of an X and vice versa.

This is what I have so far

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="U1TS.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <br>

        <button onclick="Restart()">Restart</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var c1 = 1
            var c2 = 1
            var c3 = 1
            var c4 = 1
            var c5 = 1
            var c6 = 1
            var c7 = 1
            var c8 = 1
            var c9 = 1

            var cup1 = 2
            var cup2 = 2
            var cup3 = 2
            var cup4 = 2
            var cup5 = 2
            var cup6 = 2
            var cup7 = 2
            var cup8 = 2
            var cup9 = 2
            //Line horizontale et verticale
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(40,145);
            context.lineTo(360,145);
            context.lineWidth = 5
            context.lineCap = 'round';
            context.stroke();


            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(40,260);
            context.lineTo(360,260);
            context.lineCap = 'round';
            context.stroke();


            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(260,40);
            context.lineTo(260,360);
            context.lineCap = 'round';
            context.stroke();


            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(140,40);
            context.lineTo(140,360);
            context.lineCap = 'round';
            context.stroke();

            context.font = "italic bold 30pt Calibri"
            context.fillText("1", 75, 325);
            context.fillText("2", 190, 325);
            context.fillText("3", 305, 325);
            context.fillText("4", 75, 215);
            context.fillText("5", 190, 215);
            context.fillText("6", 305, 215);
            context.fillText("7", 75, 105);
            context.fillText("8", 190, 105);
            context.fillText("9", 305, 105);

            function Restart(){
                document.location.reload(true);
            }

            document.onkeydown = Nombre;
            Nombreup1 = 49; Nombreup2 = 50; Nombreup3 = 51;
            Nombreup4   = 52; Nombreup5 = 53; Nombreup6 = 54;
            Nombreup7   = 55; Nombreup8 = 56; Nombreup9 = 57;
            Nombre7 = 103; Nombre8 = 104; Nombre9 = 105;
            Nombre4 = 100; Nombre5 = 101; Nombre6 = 102;
            Nombre3 = 99; Nombre2 = 98; Nombre1 = 97;
            function Nombre(e){
                toucheCourante = e.keyCode;

                if (toucheCourante == Nombre7){
                    lettreO7();

                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre8){
                    lettreO8();

                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre9){
                    lettreO9();


                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre6){
                    lettreO6();


                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre5){
                    lettreO5();


                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre4){
                    lettreO4();


                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre3){
                    lettreO3();


                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre2){
                    lettreO2();


                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre1){
                    lettreO1();
                }
                /////////////////////////////////////////

                if (toucheCourante == Nombreup7){
                    lettreX7();

                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup8){
                    lettreX8();

                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup9){
                    lettreX9();

                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup6){
                    lettreX6();

                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup5){
                    lettreX5();

                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup4){
                    lettreX4();

                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup3){
                    lettreX3();

                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup2){
                    lettreX2();

                } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup1){
                    lettreX1();
                }
            }


            function lettreO1()
            {
                lettreO = new Image();
                lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
                lettreO.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(lettreO, 40, 265,95,93);
                }
             }

             function lettreX1()
             {
                 lettreX = new Image();
                 lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
                 lettreX.onload = function(){
                     context.drawImage(lettreX, 40, 265,95,93);
                 }
             }

             function lettreO2()
             {
                 lettreO = new Image();
                 lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
                 lettreO.onload = function(){
                     context.drawImage(lettreO, 145, 265,110,93);
                 }
             }

             function lettreX2()
             {
                 lettreX = new Image();
                 lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
                 lettreX.onload = function(){
                     context.drawImage(lettreX, 145, 265,110,93);
                 }
              }

             function lettreO3()
             {
                 lettreO = new Image();
                 lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
                 lettreO.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(lettreO, 265, 265,95,93);
                 }
             }

             function lettreX3()
             {
                 lettreX = new Image();
                 lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
                 lettreX.onload = function(){
                     context.drawImage(lettreX, 265, 265,95,93);
                 }
             }

            function lettreO4()
            {
                 lettreO = new Image();
                 lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
                 lettreO.onload = function(){
                     context.drawImage(lettreO, 40,149,95,107);

                 }
             }

            function lettreX4()
            {
                lettreX = new Image();
                lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
                lettreX.onload = function(){
                   context.drawImage(lettreX, 40,149,95,107);

                }
            }

            function lettreO5()
            {
                lettreO = new Image();
                lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
                lettreO.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(lettreO, 145,149,110,107);

                }
            }

            function lettreX5()
            {
               lettreX = new Image();
               lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
               lettreX.onload = function(){
                   context.drawImage(lettreX, 145,149,110,107);

               }
            }

            function lettreO6()
            {
                lettreO = new Image();
                lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
                lettreO.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(lettreO, 265,149,95,107);
                }
            }

           function lettreX6()
           {
               lettreX = new Image();
               lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
               lettreX.onload = function(){
                   context.drawImage(lettreX, 265,149,95,107);

               }
           }

           function lettreO7()
           {
               lettreO = new Image();
               lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
               lettreO.onload = function(){
                   context.drawImage(lettreO, 40,40,95,101);
               }
            }

            function lettreX7()
            {
                lettreX = new Image();
                lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
                lettreX.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(lettreX, 40,40,95,101);

                }
            }

            function lettreO8()
            {
                lettreO = new Image();
                lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
                lettreO.onload = function(){
                 context.drawImage(lettreO, 145,40,110,101);

               }
            }
            function lettreX8()
            {
                lettreX = new Image();
                lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
                lettreX.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(lettreX, 145,40,110,101);

                }
            }
            function lettreO9()
            {
                lettreO = new Image();
                lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
                lettreO.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(lettreO, 265,40,95,101);
                }
            }

            function lettreX9()
            {
                lettreX = new Image();
                lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
                lettreX.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(lettreX, 265,40,95,101);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200929/discussion-on-question-by-adel-how-to-make-a-tic-tac-toe-game-using-only-context).

Comment: I cant even see the edits, can you please put it in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

We talked in the chat, but since I don't know when we will be on SO at the same time, I'm posting a solution. I still can help you step by step if you want to.

First, I cleaned and simplified some parts of your code to avoid to much work:

1. I put all the code designed to draw the grid in a `drawGrid(context)` function:

From:

```
// Line horizontale et verticale
```

To:

```
context.fillText("9", 305, 105);
```

2. Then, I rewrote the `function Nombre(e) {...}` function.

I used a keyboard map:

```
    var KEYBOARD = {
        NUMBER_UP_1: 49,
        ...
        NUMBER_UP_9: 57,
        NUMBER_1: 97,
        ...
        NUMBER_9: 105,
    };
```

I renamed the function `function onKeyDown(e) {...}`, because `Nombre(e)` isn't very explicit and may be confused with the `Number(n)` function.

I deduced the letter from the keyCode. It's an `X` if the `keyCode` is in *[49, ..., 57]*, or an `O` if the `keyCode` is in *[97, ..., 105]*.

Then, the calculation `keyCode - {firstKeyCodeForCurrentLetter} - 1` gives you the number on the pressed key. For example, if you press *50*, you have: `50 - 49 + 1 = 2`, and according to the keyboard map, *50* is associated with the key *UP_2*.

Then, whenever a number key is pressed (except 0), I check if any player has already played here. I created a `letterAt(memoryContext, position)` function that returns true if a player has already played at the position, false otherwise. If the player hasn't, then I save the move with a `memorizeMove(memoryContext, letter, position)` that draws in the `memoryCanvas`, then I update the main canvas by draw either an `X` or a `O` on it.

Finally, I determine if there is a winner with a `winOrLoss(memoryContext)` function that returns either a letter: `'O'` or `'X'`, or an empty string `''` if there's no winner yet.

I didn't handle the draw nor the fact that each player must wait his turn to play. So a player can play twice in a row. But that's something you can fix. There isn't any proper game over either: if a player wins, there's an alert, that's all, the game can still continue after that.

But the `restart()` works: I initialized everything we needed in this function, so that every time it's called, it clears both canvases and initializes variables.

I also rewrote the `lettreX1()`, `lettreO3()` and so on, functions because: no need to load the same image each time you want to draw. Load once and use as many times as you want. Then, you just have to give the `x,y` position to a function to draw the image where you want, reducing your 18 functions to only one.

3. To save the game's state, you didn't want to use variables (like an array or a matrix to know which moves has already been played for instance), so we agreed to use a secondary canvas. This canvas is 3x3 in size. Each time a player plays, if the move is allowed, then we draw one pixel of this canvas, which indicates that the position isn't empty anymore. A player a color. I did this with the `memorizeMove(memoryContext, letter, position)` function:

```
function memorizeMove(memoryContext, letter, position) {
    memoryContext.fillStyle = letter === `O` ? 'red' : 'blue';
    var coords = getCoordinatesFromPosition(position);
    memoryContext.fillRect(coords.x, coords.y, 1, 1);
}
```

It sets the color according to the player's letter (O -> red, X -> blue), gets the **x,y** coordinates from the **position** in the grid, then draws a pixel, that is to say a 1x1 rectangle, at this position with the set color.

4. To check if a move is allowed, I use the `letterAt(memoryContext, position)` function, which converts the pixel color (red, blue or blank) into a letter or an empty string. I could have just return true or false, but I needed the letters in the `winOrLoss(memoryContext)` function, and I thought that it may also be useful later to know which player has played here, if any.

```
function letterAt(memoryContext, position) {
    var color = getPixelAt(memoryContext, position);

  return color === 'red' 
    ? 'O'
    : color === 'blue'
        ? 'X'
      : '';
}
```

It uses a `getPixelAt(memoryContext, position)` that returns the pixel's color on the `memoryContext` of the 2nd canvas at the specified `position`, as seen together. It converts the `position` into `x,y` coordinates, then gets the pixel at `x,y`, gets its **RGBA** colors and returns its color.

```
function getPixelAt(memoryContext, position) {
  var coords = getCoordinatesFromPosition(position);
  var pixel = memoryContext.getImageData(coords.x, coords.y, 1, 1);
  var data = pixel.data;
  var red = data[0];
  var blue = data[2];
  var color = '';
  if (red === 255) {
    color = 'red';
  } else if (blue === 255) {
    color = 'blue';
  }
  return color;
}
```

5. I was a bit lazy when I wrote the `getCoordinatesFromPosition(position)` function... In fact, you're supposed to use a combination of **%** and **/** but since your grid is inverted (top-left is a 7, not a 1), I thought that it might be trickier than expected, so I made something very simple instead, with ifs only.

```
function getCoordinatesFromPosition(position) {
    var x = [1, 4, 7].includes(position) 
        ? 0
        : [2, 5, 8].includes(position) 
            ? 1
            : 2;
    var y = position < 4 
        ? 2
        : position < 7
            ? 1
            : 0;
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

6. Lastly, for the `winOrLoss(memoryContext)` function, I read the canvas using the `letterAt(memoryContext, i)` function and store them in an array. Then I compared the letters between each others, **horizontally**, **vertically** and in **diagonal**, looking for 3 identical letters. It returns `true` if the condition is met, `false` otherwise.

```
function winOrLoss(memoryContext) {
    var letters = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        letters.push(letterAt(memoryContext, i));
  }

  if (letters[0] === letters[1] && letters[1] === letters[2] && letters[0] !== ''
        || letters[3] === letters[4] && letters[4] === letters[5] && letters[3] !== ''
        || letters[6] === letters[7] && letters[7] === letters[8] && letters[6] !== ''
        || letters[0] === letters[3] && letters[3] === letters[6] && letters[0] !== ''
        || letters[1] === letters[4] && letters[4] === letters[7] && letters[1] !== ''
        || letters[2] === letters[5] && letters[4] === letters[8] && letters[2] !== ''
        || letters[0] === letters[4] && letters[4] === letters[8] && letters[0] !== ''
        || letters[2] === letters[4] && letters[4] === letters[7] && letters[2] !== ''
      ) {
    return letters[0];
  }
}
```

As usual, here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nmerinian/2h87Ltr9/75/